# Building object hierarchy from a 'namespace' string

Tags: javascript, string, enumeration

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string representing a namespace (e.g. "MyCompany.UI.LoginPage") and defines each segment of the namespace as an object if it doesn't already exist. For example, if "MyCompany.UI.LoginPage" wasn't an object, it would evaluate this:

```
MyCompany = {};
MyCompany.UI = {};
MyCompany.UI.LoginPage = {};
```

I would like to do this by enumerating each character of the "namespace" (string) argument and defining each object as the enumeration reaches period characters.

How can I enumerate the characters of a string in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

You can access the characters of a string directly by its index, using the [`String.prototype.charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/charAt) method:

```
var str = "foo";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  alert(str.charAt(i));
}
```

But I don't think that you want to traverse your *namespace string* character by character, you can use the [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/split) method, to get an array containing the *namespace levels* using the dot (`.`) character as a separator, e.g.:

```
var levels = "MyCompany.UI.LoginPage".split('.');
// levels is an array: ["MyCompany", "UI", "LoginPage"]
```

But I think your question goes *further* to this, and I will give you a more advanced starting point, I made a recursive function that will allow you to do exactly what you want, initialize several nested object levels using a string:

**Usage:**

```
initializeNS('MyCompany.UI.LoginPage');
// that will create a MyCompany global object

// you can use it on an object to avoid globals also
var topLevel = {};
initializeNS('Foo.Bar.Baz', topLevel);

// or
var One = initializeNS('Two.Three.Four', {});
```

**Implementation:**

```
function initializeNS(ns, obj) {
  var global = (function () { return this;})(), // reference to the global object
      levels = ns.split('.'), first = levels.shift();
  obj = obj || global; //if no object argument supplied declare a global property
  obj[first] = obj[first] || {}; // initialize the "level"
  if (levels.length) { // recursion condition
    initializeNS(levels.join('.'), obj[first]);
  }
  return obj[first]; // return a reference to the top level object
}
```

You will have to improve this function, for example you will need to sanitize the string...

Comment: I'd suggest changing `obj[first] = {};` to `obj[first] = obj[first] || {};`, so you don't overwrite existing sub-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string into an array of characters with this code:

```
var $letterArray = [];

for (var $i = 1; $i <= $yourString.length; $i++)
{
    $letterArray[$i] = $yourStringtring.substring(($i - 1), $i);
}
```

Then you can enumerate over each character in the string array `$letterArrary`

Comment: Got enough dollar signs there?

Comment: I think that using `substring` to get only one character is quite expensive when we have the `charAt` method.

Comment: You're welcome @Chris, JFTR to convert a string to a one-character string array, you can also use the `split` method with an empty string argument, e.g.: `"foo".split("");` will give you an array that looks like: `["f", "o", "o"]`

Comment: I wasn't sure if the .split() method worked with an empty arg.  Good to know.

Comment: @icktoofay It has that many dollar signs because this script is **money**!  :-)