# JavaScript function to create a structured Object from a String?

Tags: javascript, string, function, object

Could someone help me to create a JavaScript function that would turn the string below into an Object?

```
var structure = 'user.location.city';
```

When ran through the JavaScript function would return an object structured like this:

```
user: {
  location: {
    city: {}
  }
}
```

I came up with the code below, but the object is messed up:

```
var path = structure.split('.');
var tmp_obj = {};
for ( var x = 1; x < path.length; x++ ) {
   tmp_obj[path[x]] = {};
};
```

I don't know how to add the "city" Object to the "location" Object.

Comment: This SO question might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640727/javascript-nested-objects-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var path = structure.split('.');
var tmp_obj = {};
var obj = tmp_obj;
for(var x = 1; x < path.length; x++) {
    tmp_obj[path[x]] = {};
    tmp_obj = tmp_obj[path[x]];
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/VjFiOGl2AC83HcLGQTJv?p=preview
You are not using the "obj" variable? Why don't you count from 0 instead of 1?

Comment: An alternative answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029546/create-a-javascript-object-from-string