# Setting a depth in an object literal by a string of dot notation?

Tags: javascript

There are plenty of solutions out there to check/access an object literal giving a string of dot notation, but what I need to do is SET an object literal based on a string of dot notation. It is very technical why I need to do this, and if it isn't feasible I will come up with a different solution.

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
var obj = { 
   'a': 1, 
   'b': 2, 
    'c': { 
      'nest': true 
    } 
};
```

I'd like a function that would work something like this:

```
setDepth(obj, 'c.nest', false);
```

That would change the obj to this:

```
var obj = { 
   'a': 1, 
   'b': 2, 
    'c': { 
      'nest': false
    } 
};
```

I've been trying to an hour and haven't been able to come up with a good solution yet. Another help would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript nested objects from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640727/javascript-nested-objects-from-string) and [JavaScript function to create a structured Object from a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203789/javascript-function-to-create-a-structured-object-from-a-string)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate of those, I want to modify a certain property of an existing object and not touch the rest of the object. So the obj I made above already has values set: 'obj.a', 'obj.b', 'obj.c' and i just want to make a change to obj.c.nest

Comment: It's almost exactly the same logic, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My version:

```
function setDepth(obj, path, value) {
    var tags = path.split("."), len = tags.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj = obj[tags[i]];
    }
    obj[tags[len]] = value;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Sxz2z/

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it:

```
function setDepth(obj, path, value) {
    var levels = path.split(".");
    var curLevel = obj;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < levels.length-1) {
        curLevel = curLevel[levels[i]];
        i++;
    }
    curLevel[levels[levels.length-1]] = value;
}
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/ETyqq/)

Answer (score 2):

I modified Elliot's answer to let it add new nodes if they don't exist.

```js
var settings = {};

function set(key, value) {
  /**
         * Dot notation loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253459/607354
         */
  var levels = key.split(".");
  var curLevel = settings;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < levels.length-1) {
    if(typeof curLevel[levels[i]] === 'undefined') {
      curLevel[levels[i]] = {};
    }

    curLevel = curLevel[levels[i]];
    i++;
  }
  curLevel[levels[levels.length-1]] = value;

  return settings;
}

set('this.is.my.setting.key', true);
set('this.is.my.setting.key2', 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
new Function('_', 'val', '_.' + path + ' = val')(obj, value);
```

In your case:

```
var obj = { 
   'a': 1, 
   'b': 2, 
    'c': { 
      'nest': true 
    } 
};

new Function('_', 'val', '_.c.nest' + ' = val')(obj, false);
```

Comment: This uses runtime evaluation, which is a no-no when alternative solutions are available, especially easy alternatives as stated in other answers. There is a reason why many sites use the Content-Security-Policy header to disable the `eval()` function.

Comment: You've pointed to a thread that has a bunch of valid reasons not to use eval, especially for such a simple method as the question in this stack overflow post.