# add elements to object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an object given an array of objects

```
const someArray = [
  {
    name: 'x.y',
    value: 'Something for Y'
  },
  {
    name: 'x.a.z',
    value: 'Something for Z'
  }
]
```

to look like this

```
{ 
  x: { 
    a: { 
        z: 'Something for Z' 
    },
    y: 'Something for Y' 
  } 
}
```

I have this code

```
const buildObj = data => {
  let obj = {}
  
  data.forEach(item => {
      let items = item.name.split('.')
      items.reduce((acc, val, idx) => {
        acc[val] = (idx === items.length - 1) ? item.value : {}
        return acc[val]
      }, obj)
  })

  return obj
}

buildObj(someArray)
```

but it doesn't include the y keypair. what's missing?

Comment: SO can you walk me through what that conversion is?  you check name and then create an object structure based on that? then if a key already exists you just update that key with a the new value and you create this structure based on the a.b.c structure so a.b.c => { a: { b: { c{} } }

Comment: yea pretty much

Comment: Okay cool and any value is fair game, correct?

Comment: See [Create an object out of dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14891040/4642212). Other than that, why not step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @GrantHerman fair game

Comment: And is the last item in the dot notations get the value of the array ?

Comment: I think I have it going to put something together

Comment: What happens if you have `x.y` with a value and then `x.y.z` with another value? What should that result look like?

Comment: let's keep it simple with just the data in someArray

Comment: `acc[val] = (idx === items.length - 1) ? item.value : {}` overwrites the previous `x` property with another empty object. Look into [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: @user4642212 can you show me how with this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create an object, then for each dotted path, navigate through the object, creating new object properties as you go for missing parts, then assign the value to the inner-most property.

```js
const someArray = [{"name":"x.y","value":"Something for Y"},{"name":"x.a.z","value":"Something for Z"}]

const t1 = performance.now()

const obj = someArray.reduce((o, { name, value }) => {
  // create a path array
  const path = name.split(".")
  
  // extract the inner-most object property name
  const prop = path.pop()
  
  // find or create the inner-most object
  const inner = path.reduce((i, segment) => {
    // if the segment property doesn't exist or is not an object,
    // create it
    if (typeof i[segment] !== "object") {
      i[segment] = {}
    }
    return i[segment]
  }, o)
  
  // assign the value
  inner[prop] = value
  
  return o
}, {})

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(obj)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using for loops and checking nesting from the top down.

```js
const someArray = [
  {
    name: 'x.y',
    value: 'Something for Y'
  },
  {
    name: 'x.a.z',
    value: 'Something for Z'
  }
]



function parseArr(arr) {
  const output = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const {name, value} = arr[i];
    const keys = name.split('.');
    
    let parent = output;
    for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      const key = keys[j];
      if (!parent.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        parent[key] = j === keys.length - 1 ? value : {};
      }
      parent = parent[key];
    }

  }

  return output;
}

console.log(parseArr(someArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ABD at this point but I did it with a recursive builder of the path.

```js
const someArray = [
    {
        name: 'x.y',
        value: 'Something for Y'
    },
    {
        name: 'x.a.z',
        value: 'Something for Z'
    }
]

const createPath = (path, value) => {
    if(path.length === 1){
        let obj = {}
        obj[path.shift()] = value
        return obj
    }
    let key = path.shift();
    let outObject = {}
    outObject[key] = { ...createPath(path, value) }
    return outObject
}
const createObjectBasedOnDotNotation = (arr) => {
    let outObject = {}
    for(let objKey in arr){
        const { name, value } = arr[objKey];
        let object = createPath(name.split("."), value)
        let mainKey = Object.keys(object)[0];
        !outObject[mainKey] ?
            outObject[mainKey] = {...object[mainKey]} :
            outObject[mainKey] = {
                ...outObject[mainKey],
                ...object[mainKey]
            }
    }
    return outObject
}
console.log(createObjectBasedOnDotNotation(someArray))
```