# How do I build my JSON object using two parts when concatenated together produces the correct JSON data path

Tags: javascript, json

Is this possible to do, or how do I do it?

```
arrayElement = new Object();
JSONkey = jsonData.table[0].key; // key in table[0] is "ident/Lesson/Value"
JSONkey = JSONkey.replace(/\//g, '.'); // now JSONkey is "ident.Lesson.Value"

arrayElement.JSONkey = "value1" // Can I do this or how would I?
```

So `arrayElement.JSONkey` is the same as `arrayElement.ident.Lesson.Value`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does `jsonData` look like? What do you want `arrayElement` to look like at the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: There's a library for that called [jsonpath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/f0e055a3ba4a8c9966ae7f7cb9b21e10d99d05d9/json-path-web-test/src/main/resources/webapp/js/jsonpath-0.8.0.js).  You might have to adapt your script to it's format, however.

Comment: @JamesThorpe This question is about setting a nested value I think, so it's not really a duplicate. The question you pointed is about accessing.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Fair enough.  How about [this one as a dupe target then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253307/setting-a-depth-in-an-object-literal-by-a-string-of-dot-notation)?

Comment: Yes, that's the right one, I think I should improve my searching skills. Was looking for that :D

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you, yes I agree, duplicate - should I just delete my question or can I close it myself? I did vote to close it...

Comment: @DemiSheep leave the question open, perhaps flag it as a duplicate.  It will eventually get closed as a duplicate, but that's fine - search engines will still index it giving a broader range of terms for this sort of issue.  If people end up here as a result of that, they'll get pointed at the other question

Comment: @JamesThorpe Excellent point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrayElement = new Object();
JSONkey = jsonData.table[0].key; // key in table[0] is "ident/Lesson/Value"
JSONkey = JSONkey.replace(/\//g, '.'); // now JSONkey is "ident.Lesson.Value"

deepRef(arrayElement, JSONkey, "value1");

function deepRef(ref, key, value) {
    var segments = key.split("."),
        n = segments.length;
    for (var i=0, skey; i<n; i++) {
        skey = segments[i];
        if (i < n - 1) {
            ref[skey] = {};
            ref = ref[skey];
        } else {
            ref[skey] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does seem to work, thank you. However there is a more simplified version in the other link listed at the top of my question.