# Create a JavaScript object with arrays from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that creates an object from a string, but some of my objects need to be arrays.
For example, from this string:

`"config.content.contents.0.slots.0.adConfig.ref1:hello"` is suppose to be:

```js
{
    config: {
        content: {
            contents: [
                {
                    slots: [
                        {
                            adConfig: {
                                ref1: "hello"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I found this code that helps but don't handle arrays. Source: [Create a JavaScript object from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029546/create-a-javascript-object-from-string)

```js
var createObject = function (model, name, value) {
    var nameParts = name.split("."),
        currentObject = model;
    for (var i in nameParts) {
        var part = nameParts[i];
        if (i == nameParts.length - 1) {
            currentObject[part] = value;
            break;
        }
        if (typeof currentObject[part] == "undefined") {
            currentObject[part] = {};
        }
        currentObject = currentObject[part];
    }
};
```

and use it like this:

```
var model = {};
createObject(model, "some.example.here", "hello");
createObject(model, "some.example.there", "hi");
createObject(model, "other.example", "heyo");
```

I can also have this string:
`"config.content.contents.0.slots.1.adConfig.ref1:goodbye"`

I thought using the `isNaN` function to know to make it an array.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: _"I thought using the isNaN function to know to make it an array"_... sounds like a good idea, did you try it? FYI your example result is not valid JS

Comment: Lodash has a method for this already... `_.set(model, ...string.split(":"))`. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

Comment: sure, but I got stuck with what to push to the array, I thought to send in recursive "slots.0.adConfig.ref1" to the function but I couldn't make it work

Comment: The expected output is invalid

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript dotted object keys to object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49302780/283366)

Comment: `.split` returns an array of strings, so isNaN will always be true.