# Recursive nested property creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to recursively build an object with a tree of properties based on a MongoDB-ish selector "top.middle.bottom". There are some underscorejs helpers as well:

```
function setNestedPropertyValue(obj, fields, val) {
  if (fields.indexOf(".") === -1) { 
    // On last property, set the value
    obj[fields] = val; 
    return obj; // Recurse back up
  } else {
    var oneLevelLess = _.first(fields.split("."));
    var remainingLevels = _.rest(fields.split(".")).join(".");
    // There are more property levels remaining, set a sub with a recursive call
    obj[oneLevelLess] = setNestedPropertyValue( {}, remainingLevels, val);
  }
}

setNestedPropertyValue({}, "grandpaprop.papaprop.babyprop", 1);
```

Desired:

```
{ 
  grandpaprop: {
    papaprop: {
      babyprop: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Outcome:

```
undefined
```

Helps and hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not returning `obj` in the second branch. That said, why are you using recursion in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically add to a variably-nested object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206268/how-can-i-programmatically-add-to-a-variably-nested-object)

Comment: @Jack, was using recursion because I thought it was fun and (evidently) something I need excercising.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for mentioning that question. I guess that's the approach Jack was hinting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of recursion I would choose for an iterative solution:

```
function setNestedPropertyValue(obj, fields, val)
{
  fields = fields.split('.');

  var cur = obj,
  last = fields.pop();

  fields.forEach(function(field) {
      cur[field] = {};
      cur = cur[field];
  });

  cur[last] = val;

  return obj;
}

setNestedPropertyValue({}, "grandpaprop.papaprop.babyprop", 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

And here is another version thanks to the suggestions by Scott Sauyet:

```js
function setPath(obj, [first, ...rest], val) {
    if (rest.length == 0) {
        return {...obj, [first]: val}
    }
    let nestedObj = obj[first] || {};
    return {...obj, [first]: setPath(nestedObj, rest, val)};
}

function setNestedPropertyValue(obj, field, val) {
    return setPath(obj, field.split('.'), val);
}

// example
let test_obj = {};
test_obj = setNestedPropertyValue(test_obj, "foo.bar.baz", 1);
test_obj = setNestedPropertyValue(test_obj, "foo.bar.baz1", 1);
// will output {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":1,"baz1":1}}}, while in the original version only "baz1" will be set
console.log(JSON.stringify(test_obj));
```

- It's plain javascript
- It only appends properties and will not override a top level object
- setNestedPropertyValue() does not mutate the passed object (although keep in mind it only returns a shallow copy of the object, so some properties may be shared references between the original object and the new one)

---

I know this is old, but I needed exactly that kind of function and wasn't happy with the implementation, so here is my version:

```js
function setNestedPropertyValue(obj, field, val) {
 if (field.indexOf(".") === -1) {
  obj[field] = val;
 } else {
  let fields = field.split(".");
  let topLevelField = fields.shift();
  let remainingFields = fields.join(".");
  if (obj[topLevelField] == null) {
   obj[topLevelField] = {};
  }
  setNestedPropertyValue(obj[topLevelField], remainingFields, val);
 }
}

// example
let test_obj = {};
setNestedPropertyValue(test_obj, "foo.bar.baz", 1);
setNestedPropertyValue(test_obj, "foo.bar.baz1", 1);
// will output {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":1,"baz1":1}}}, while in the original version only "baz1" will be set
console.log(JSON.stringify(test_obj));
```

- It's plain javascript
- It only appends properties and will not override a top level object
- setNestedPropertyValue() does not return the object so it is clear that it mutates the passed object

Comment: For me, that third bullet is a serious negative.  Mutating input data is the work of the devil!  :-)

Comment: My own non-mutating version might be something like this functin taking an array for the `field`: `const setPath = (obj, [f, ...fs], val) =>f == undefined ? obj :  {...obj, [f]: fs .length ? setPath (obj [f] || {}, fs, val): val}`, with a wrapper to use a dot-separated string: `const setNestedPropertyValue = (obj, field, val) => setPath (obj, field.split('.'), val)`.  It's not particularly sophisticated, and a library I maintain does quite a bit more, but it's enough for the cases here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Haha, I totally agree about mutating input data :) I only meant it was a slight improvement on the original version which was a weird mix of the two.

Thank you for your suggestions! I only played with a little bit of JS recently and I haven't come across the spread/rest operator. I've updated my answer based on your suggestions. I just prefer a more verbose approach so I can follow what's going on...

Comment: Rest/spread can DRY out a lot of code.  It's definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jack in the question, I was not returning my object in the last line in the `else` statement. By adding this, it is now working:

```
 obj[oneLevelLess] = setNestedPropertyValue( {}, remainingLevels, val);
   return obj; // Add this line
 }
```